# Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character in numeric value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to POST form data to api gateway which then sends it to lambda for processing. However, I get

```
{
  "message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character (\'-\' (code 45)) 
    in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value\n 
    at [Source: (byte[])\"----------------------------086228525798973846089611\r\nContent- 
    Disposition: form-data; name=\"first_name\"\r\n\r\nfake\r\n--------------------------- 
   -086228525798973846089611\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
   name=\"last_name\"\r\n\r\nname\r\n--------------------------- 
   -086228525798973846089611\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
   name=\"email\"\r\n\r\nfakename1@something.com\r\n--------------------------- 
   -086228525798973846089611\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"mobile\"\r\n\r\n\r\n- 
   ---------------------------086228525798973\"[truncated 752 bytes]; line: 1, column: 3]"
}
```

In the cloudwatch logs I can see lambda gives this error: `Lambda invocation failed with status: 400.` Can't see any errors in lambda logs just api gateway logs.

My api gateway POST method looks like this:
[image]

**Edit**:
Adding image of form I am trying to submit that the API isn't liking:
[image: formdata]

Any ideas how to POST through to lambda without api gateway transformations or other issue?

Comment: Have you tried using Lambda proxy integration? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html

Comment: Thanks but then I get this error {"message": "Missing Authentication Token"}, does this mean I will need to include authentication before I can test it?

Comment: Did you re-deploy API after changing to proxy? Missing authentication token is not necessarily an authentication issue. It could also mean your URL or the HTTP method is incorrect

Comment: URL is fine. Im just getting the URL from the "Stage Editor" which is something like `https://blah.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stage` but I believe I now need to add a string in /{proxy+} part but not sure what to do at this point. The main objective is to send form data through api gateway to lambda at which point I can retrieve the form data from event object.

Comment: I just added a random string for URI part after /stage but I still get the original error again "Could not parse request body into json".

Comment: There is something in the form data that API Gateway isn't liking. Could you share that if it doesn't have any sensitive information?

Comment: @SurajBhatia thanks, added image above

Comment: I was able to pass similar form data from API to Lambda without any error. Can you print the event in Lambda and confirm if the function is getting invoked and you see some data coming in?

Comment: @SurajBhatia You are right, using lambda proxy in Integration Request and then making HTTP Status in Method Response be proxy works. I will do a proper answer later if no one else does in the next few days.